# Android Studio Java rewrite code from getLastTimeUsed too getTotalTimeInForeground

Tags: java, android

I found some code on GitHub, which can register and display the usageStats of an android device, but the usageStats outputs as getLastTimeUsed and I would like it to display as getTotalTimeInForeground, I have tried just changing the code everywhere but the output resulted in a constant time of 1/1/70, not the real time that was spent on an application, please help me discover the solution.

This is the code for the different classes:

```
public class UsageStatVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView appIcon;
    private TextView appName;
    private TextView lastTimeUsed;

    public UsageStatVH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        appIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        appName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        lastTimeUsed = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_used);
    }

    public void bindTo(UsageStatsWrapper usageStatsWrapper) {
        appIcon.setImageDrawable(usageStatsWrapper.getAppIcon());
        appName.setText(usageStatsWrapper.getAppName());
        if (usageStatsWrapper.getUsageStats() == null) {
            lastTimeUsed.setText(R.string.last_time_used_never);
        } else if (usageStatsWrapper.getUsageStats().getLastTimeUsed() == 0 L) {
            lastTimeUsed.setText(R.string.last_time_used_never);
        } else {
            lastTimeUsed.setText(App.getApp().getString(R.string.last_time_used,
                DateUtils.format(usageStatsWrapper)));
        }
    }
}

public class DateUtils {

    public static String format(UsageStatsWrapper usageStatsWrapper) {

        DateFormat format = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
        return format.format(usageStatsWrapper.getUsageStats().getLastTimeUsed());
    }
}

public final class UsageStatsWrapper implements Comparable < UsageStatsWrapper > {

    private final UsageStats usageStats;
    private final Drawable appIcon;
    private final String appName;

    public UsageStatsWrapper(UsageStats usageStats, Drawable appIcon, String appName) {
        this.usageStats = usageStats;
        this.appIcon = appIcon;
        this.appName = appName;
    }

    public UsageStats getUsageStats() {
        return usageStats;
    }

    public Drawable getAppIcon() {
        return appIcon;
    }

    public String getAppName() {
        return appName;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull UsageStatsWrapper usageStatsWrapper) {
        if (usageStats == null && usageStatsWrapper.getUsageStats() != null) {
            return 1;
        } else if (usageStatsWrapper.getUsageStats() == null && usageStats != null) {
            return -1;
        } else if (usageStatsWrapper.getUsageStats() == null && usageStats == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return Long.compare(usageStatsWrapper.getUsageStats().getLastTimeUsed(),
                usageStats.getLastTimeUsed());
        }
    }
}

public class UsagePresenter implements UsageContract.Presenter {

    private static final int flags = PackageManager.GET_META_DATA |
        PackageManager.GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES |
        PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES;

    private UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager;
    private PackageManager packageManager;
    private UsageContract.View view;
    private final Context context;

    public UsagePresenter(Context context, UsageContract.View view) {
        usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService("usagestats");
        packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        this.view = view;
        this.context = context;
    }

    private long getStartTime() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
        return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public void retrieveUsageStats() {
        if (!checkForPermission(context)) {
            view.onUserHasNoPermission();
            return;
        }

        List < String > installedApps = getInstalledAppList();
        Map < String, UsageStats > usageStats = usageStatsManager.queryAndAggregateUsageStats(getStartTime(), System.currentTimeMillis());
        List < UsageStats > stats = new ArrayList < > ();
        stats.addAll(usageStats.values());

        List < UsageStatsWrapper > finalList = buildUsageStatsWrapper(installedApps, stats);
        view.onUsageStatsRetrieved(finalList);
    }

    private boolean checkForPermission(Context context) {
        AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        int mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow(OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS, myUid(), context.getPackageName());
        return mode == MODE_ALLOWED;
    }

    private List < String > getInstalledAppList() {
        List < ApplicationInfo > infos = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(flags);
        List < String > installedApps = new ArrayList < > ();
        for (ApplicationInfo info: infos) {
            installedApps.add(info.packageName);
        }
        return installedApps;
    }

    private List < UsageStatsWrapper > buildUsageStatsWrapper(List < String > packageNames, List < UsageStats > usageStatses) {
        List < UsageStatsWrapper > list = new ArrayList < > ();
        for (String name: packageNames) {
            boolean added = false;
            for (UsageStats stat: usageStatses) {
                if (name.equals(stat.getPackageName())) {
                    added = true;
                    list.add(fromUsageStat(stat));
                }
            }
            if (!added) {
                list.add(fromUsageStat(name));
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(list);
        return list;
    }

    private UsageStatsWrapper fromUsageStat(String packageName) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        try {
            ApplicationInfo ai = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
            return new UsageStatsWrapper(null, packageManager.getApplicationIcon(ai), packageManager.getApplicationLabel(ai).toString());

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }

    private UsageStatsWrapper fromUsageStat(UsageStats usageStats) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        try {
            ApplicationInfo ai = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(usageStats.getPackageName(), 0);
            return new UsageStatsWrapper(usageStats, packageManager.getApplicationIcon(ai), packageManager.getApplicationLabel(ai).toString());

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you can help give me some pointers on how I can do this?

This is how it looks if I just change every getLastTimeUsed to getTotalTimeInForeground

[image: img1]